# Efficiently update several pyplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a script that is supposed to update a grid of 25 images in each iteration of a for loop.  The code is essentially this (I am leaving out extraneous stuff to keep it simple):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5,5,figsize=(3,3))

for i in range(100):
    updateImages()
    for j in range(5):
         for k in range(5):
              ax[j,k].imshow(image[j,k])
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

The problem is that it runs very, VERY slowly [and no, it is not `updateImages()` that is slow].  I believe there is a more efficient way to do this, but so far I have been unable to find any examples. Suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: The problem _might_ be that you are only _adding_ data points to the plot when always calling `imshow` instead of _replacing/updating_ them so after a lot of loops, you have to handle a lot of data. You could store the first output of `imshow` in a list like `ax` and just update the data: `list_of_images[j,k] = imshow(...)` and then in the loop `list_of_images[j,k].set_data(image[j,k])`.

Comment: @Michael this seems more like an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your program runs slow after some time might be that you are only *adding* data points to the plot when always calling `imshow` instead of *replacing/updating* them. Even though you always see only the points most recently plotted, Python has to handle a lot of data after a lot of loops which is why it becomes slow.

Instead, you could store the first output of `imshow` in a list and just *update* the data. First, create a list `list_of_images` with the same 'shape' like `ax` and store the images of the first iteration there:

```
list_of_images[j,k] = imshow(...)
```

Then in the loop over iterations, just update the data:

```
list_of_images[j,k].set_data(image[j,k])
```

This way, the amount of data Python has to handle doesn't grow with the number of iterations and your program should be stable.

---

**EDIT (by OP):**  Based on this answer, I tried the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5,5,figsize=(3,3))
image_grid = ax.copy()  # Maybe there is a less awkward way to do this

for i in range(100):
    updateImages()
    for j in range(5):
         for k in range(5):
              image_grid[j,k].set_data(image[j,k])
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

It runs very smoothly (just as fast as with a single image).  Thanks!